# Regex to remove line break when next line does not start with a given string

Tags: .net, regex

Working in .net i'm parsing a log file where some lines do not begin with '"2018'. I need a .Match clause that will find lines where the line begins with anything except the string "2018 (note that includes the double quote). When found (and this is the tricky bit) - remove the line break from the line *before* the offending line. In other words, append offending lines to the line above it.

```
"2018-02-22 10:06:10,857","[7]"," ERROR","MyApp.Web.Infrastructure.ErrorResponseCommand","ErrorResponseCMD logs Controller: webinar | Action: Index",""
"2018-02-22 10:06:37,742","[11]"," INFO ","MyApp.Web.MvcApplication","Anon Session Starts with: {""FirstPage"": ""https://www.bankwebinars.com/wp-login.php"", ""QueryString"": """", ""SessionId"": ""uhnev2dnds33dastwrdgftvm"", ""FirstCookies"": {""CookieName"": ""ASP.NET_SessionId"", ""Value"": ""uhnev2dnds33dastwrdgftvm""}}",""
"2018-02-22 10:06:48,053","[11]"," INFO ","MyApp.Web.Controllers.CartController","SessionInfo{
  ""FirstPage"": null,
  ""RemoteAddress"": ""207.46.13.159"",
  ""RemoteHost"": ""207.46.13.159"",
  ""RemoteUser"": """",
RelativeConfirmPasswordResetUrl:Account/PasswordResetConfirm
//and other non-predictable BOL patterns.
},""
"2018-02-22 10:06:10,857","[7]"," ERROR","MyApp.Web.Infrastructure.ErrorResponseCommand","ErrorResponseCMD logs Controller: webinar | Action: Index",""
```

ADDENDUM: Having tried the suggested pattern - and noting that pattern works correctly for regex101's sandbox - there must be something else wrong. Here's my current code.

```
string str = File.ReadAllText("myLog.log");            
Regex rx = new Regex("(?m)\r?\n^(?!\"2018)", RegexOptions.Singleline);
str = rx.Replace(str, "\"2018");            
File.WriteAllText("test1.txt", str);
```

I've tried a bunch of variations on the pattern - e.g. I think the RegexOption clause is equivalent to the (?m) phrase so I've tried omitting that. Singleline should be what i want since it views the whole file as a single line but I've tried Multiline mode as well. It's a Windows file so the ? qualifier between \r and \n should not be required. None of the variations have changed the output.

Comment: And what's the problem with your pattern?

Comment: or more better, what is your tried pattern?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Possible problems with your code in a top-down order

1- I saw documentation page of `File.ReadAllText()` [emphasizes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143368(v=vs.110).aspx):

> The resulting string does not contain the terminating carriage return
>   and/or line feed.

If that's the problem take a look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13520472/how-to-read-a-file-into-a-string-with-cr-lf-preserved), I'm not a .NET guru.

2- And you need to [@-quote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6134547/what-does-the-prefix-do-on-string-literals-in-c) regex string beside [caring about inner double quotation mark](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/string) (`""` denotes a `"` in @-quoted string) and removing `s` flag as well which is extra.

```
Regex rx = new Regex(@"(?m)\r?\n^(?!""2018)");
```

3- Next thing is replacement string that you provided. You should replace with nothing. A [Zero-Width Negative Lookahead Assertion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/grouping-constructs-in-regular-expressions#zerowidth_negative_lookahead_assertion) asserts and doesn't consume:

```
str = rx.Replace(str, "");
```

**[Live demo](https://ideone.com/roOkdw)**

Comment: All points spot on. Thanks! For future folk: the resolution to problem #1 was string str = File.ReadAllText("myText.txt", Encoding.ASCII);

Answer (score 2):

Here is regex replace that does the job:

```
str = Regex.Replace(str, @"\r?\n(?!""2018)", String.Empty);
```

The following code from the question is incorrect:

```
Regex rx = new Regex("(?m)\r?\n^(?!\"2018)", RegexOptions.Singleline);
str = rx.Replace(str, "\"2018");
```

`(?!\"2018)` is a negative lookahead. Like other lookarounds it does not actually capture matched text. That's why `rx.Replace(str, "\"2018")` will cause adding of `"2018` to each moved string. For example for input:

```
"2018" Line 1
"2018" Line 2
  Sub-line 1
  Sub-line 2
"2018" Line 3
```

you'll get the following result:

```
"2018" Line 1
"2018" Line 2"2018  Sub-line 1"2018  Sub-line 2
"2018" Line 3"2018
```

That's why you should replace matched parts with just an empty string. In this case you will get correct result:

```
"2018" Line 1
"2018" Line 2  Sub-line 1  Sub-line 2
"2018" Line 3
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get what I think is the desired result by doing the following:

```
Regex.Replace(logString, @"\r\n\s\s", "", RegexOptions.Multiline)
```

Comment: Based on the short snippet of sample provided yes, your answer suffices. I've edited the OP to include more variations that need to be accommodated.